# C++ memory access violation on trying to deep copy a unique pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, unique-ptr

So I have the following class as such:

```
class foo{
public:
  unique_ptr<someClass> pt;
Foo(){}
//Copy constructor
Foo(Foo& f){
  someClass * copy = f.pt.get();
  pt=unique_ptr<someClass>(copy);
}

};
```

So the above code works as intended, the copy constructor will make the current class have an exact copy of the given class. But, it also gives me a memory access violation. I tried debugging it on valgrind, but it says it has something to do with the default delete on the unique_ptr class. However, at no point in my code do I call delete.

I was wondering if there was a way to remove these memory access violations, or if there is another step I am missing to this.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable and there is a reason for that. You created a hack to override it hence the problem

Comment: You're `delete`ing the same pointer twice.

Answer (score 1):

For deep-copy, you will have to modify your copy-constructor like this:

```
Foo(Foo& f) : pt( new someClass( *f.pt.get() ) ) {}
```

And you will have to define a copy-constructor for `someClass` as well if not already defined.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a deep copy, it's a shallow copy at best, you are getting the pointer out of the smart pointer and put it a second one.

This will fail. You need to clone the object first.